# lxml fails to install with python 3.7

Tags: pip, lxml, python-3.7

I cannot install libxml in my python env to install sofort
python: Python 3.7.3
Already did: apt-get --reinstalll install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev
When trying to install libxml it calls an error about PyObject with such errors

```
398                    (PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x030600B1 && (cfunc)->flag == METH_FASTCALL ?  (*(__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)(cfunc)->func)(self, &PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_empty_tuple, 0), 0, NULL)
```

long output:

```
Collecting sofort
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/85/b51f32001315aed58dc7db71fc558b0c14b2f311f18292854f2981826910/sofort-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting lxml<4.0,>=3.5 (from sofort)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/b3/9f245de14b7696e2d2a386c0b09032a2ff6625270761d6543827e667d8de/lxml-3.8.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0,>=2.9 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sofort) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: schematics<2.0,>=1.1 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sofort) (1.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: xmltodict<1.0,>=0.9 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sofort) (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: iso8601<1.0,>=0.1 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sofort) (0.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.9->sofort) (2019.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.9->sofort) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.9->sofort) (1.25.6)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.9->sofort) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7.3 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from schematics<2.0,>=1.1->sofort) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml ... error
  Complete output from command /home/test7/myweb/env/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-o_pr8d68/lxml/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-9u9hnke4 --python-tag cp37:
  Building lxml version 3.8.0.
  Building without Cython.
  Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.32
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/home/test7/myweb/env/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyCFunction_FastCall’:
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233279:13: error: too many arguments to function ‘(PyObject * (*)(PyObject *, PyObject * const*, Py_ssize_t))meth’
       return (*((__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)meth)) (self, args, nargs, NULL);
              ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyDict_Items’:
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4532:83: error: too many arguments to function ‘(PyObject * (*)(PyObject *, PyObject * const*, Py_ssize_t))__pyx_umethod_PyDict_Type_items.func’
                 (PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x030600B1 && (cfunc)->flag == METH_FASTCALL ?  (*(__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)(cfunc)->func)(self, &PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_empty_tuple, 0), 0, NULL) :\
                                                                                    ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233529:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_CallUnboundCMethod0’
           return __Pyx_CallUnboundCMethod0(&__pyx_umethod_PyDict_Type_items, d);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSave’:
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233753:21: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       *type = tstate->exc_type;
                       ^~~~~~~~
                       curexc_type
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233754:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       *value = tstate->exc_value;
                        ^~~~~~~~~
                        curexc_value
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233755:19: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     curexc_traceback
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionReset’:
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233762:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                          ^~~~~~~~
                          curexc_type
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233763:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                           ^~~~~~~~~
                           curexc_value
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233764:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        curexc_traceback
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233765:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tstate->exc_type = type;
               ^~~~~~~~
               curexc_type
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233766:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tstate->exc_value = value;
               ^~~~~~~~~
               curexc_value
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233767:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
               curexc_traceback
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__GetException’:
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233822:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                          ^~~~~~~~
                          curexc_type
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233823:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                           ^~~~~~~~~
                           curexc_value
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233824:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        curexc_traceback
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233825:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tstate->exc_type = local_type;
               ^~~~~~~~
               curexc_type
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233826:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tstate->exc_value = local_value;
               ^~~~~~~~~
               curexc_value
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233827:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
               curexc_traceback
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSwap’:
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234160:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                          ^~~~~~~~
                          curexc_type
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234161:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                           ^~~~~~~~~
                           curexc_value
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234162:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        curexc_traceback
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234163:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tstate->exc_type = *type;
               ^~~~~~~~
               curexc_type
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234164:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tstate->exc_value = *value;
               ^~~~~~~~~
               curexc_value
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234165:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tstate->exc_traceback = *tb;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
               curexc_traceback
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyList_Pop’:
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4532:83: error: too many arguments to function ‘(PyObject * (*)(PyObject *, PyObject * const*, Py_ssize_t))__pyx_umethod_PyList_Type_pop.func’
                 (PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x030600B1 && (cfunc)->flag == METH_FASTCALL ?  (*(__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)(cfunc)->func)(self, &PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_empty_tuple, 0), 0, NULL) :\
                                                                                    ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234476:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_CallUnboundCMethod0’
       return __Pyx_CallUnboundCMethod0(&__pyx_umethod_PyList_Type_pop, L);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyDict_Values’:
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4532:83: error: too many arguments to function ‘(PyObject * (*)(PyObject *, PyObject * const*, Py_ssize_t))__pyx_umethod_PyDict_Type_values.func’
                 (PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x030600B1 && (cfunc)->flag == METH_FASTCALL ?  (*(__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)(cfunc)->func)(self, &PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_empty_tuple, 0), 0, NULL) :\
                                                                                    ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:235119:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_CallUnboundCMethod0’
           return __Pyx_CallUnboundCMethod0(&__pyx_umethod_PyDict_Type_values, d);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Compile failed: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  creating tmp
  cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInit15huy_ms.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInit15huy_ms.o
  /tmp/xmlXPathInit15huy_ms.c:2:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   main (int argc, char **argv) {
   ^~~~
  cc tmp/xmlXPathInit15huy_ms.o -lxml2 -o a.out
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml

[...]
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/home/test7/myweb/env/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyCFunction_FastCall’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233279:13: error: too many arguments to function ‘(PyObject * (*)(PyObject *, PyObject * const*, Py_ssize_t))meth’
         return (*((__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)meth)) (self, args, nargs, NULL);
                ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyDict_Items’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4532:83: error: too many arguments to function ‘(PyObject * (*)(PyObject *, PyObject * const*, Py_ssize_t))__pyx_umethod_PyDict_Type_items.func’
                   (PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x030600B1 && (cfunc)->flag == METH_FASTCALL ?  (*(__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)(cfunc)->func)(self, &PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_empty_tuple, 0), 0, NULL) :\
                                                                                      ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233529:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_CallUnboundCMethod0’
             return __Pyx_CallUnboundCMethod0(&__pyx_umethod_PyDict_Type_items, d);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSave’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233753:21: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
         *type = tstate->exc_type;
                         ^~~~~~~~
                         curexc_type
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233754:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
         *value = tstate->exc_value;
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_value
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233755:19: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
         *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_traceback
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionReset’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233762:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
         tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                            ^~~~~~~~
                            curexc_type
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233763:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
         tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                             ^~~~~~~~~
                             curexc_value
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233764:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
         tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_traceback
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233765:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
         tstate->exc_type = type;
                 ^~~~~~~~
                 curexc_type
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233766:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
         tstate->exc_value = value;
                 ^~~~~~~~~
                 curexc_value
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233767:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
         tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 curexc_traceback
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__GetException’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233822:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
         tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                            ^~~~~~~~
                            curexc_type
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233823:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
         tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                             ^~~~~~~~~
                             curexc_value
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233824:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
         tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_traceback
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233825:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
         tstate->exc_type = local_type;
                 ^~~~~~~~
                 curexc_type
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233826:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
         tstate->exc_value = local_value;
                 ^~~~~~~~~
                 curexc_value
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:233827:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
         tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 curexc_traceback
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSwap’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234160:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
         tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                            ^~~~~~~~
                            curexc_type
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234161:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
         tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                             ^~~~~~~~~
                             curexc_value
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234162:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
         tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_traceback
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234163:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
         tstate->exc_type = *type;
                 ^~~~~~~~
                 curexc_type
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234164:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
         tstate->exc_value = *value;
                 ^~~~~~~~~
                 curexc_value
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234165:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
         tstate->exc_traceback = *tb;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 curexc_traceback
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyList_Pop’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4532:83: error: too many arguments to function ‘(PyObject * (*)(PyObject *, PyObject * const*, Py_ssize_t))__pyx_umethod_PyList_Type_pop.func’
                   (PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x030600B1 && (cfunc)->flag == METH_FASTCALL ?  (*(__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)(cfunc)->func)(self, &PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_empty_tuple, 0), 0, NULL) :\
                                                                                      ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234476:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_CallUnboundCMethod0’
         return __Pyx_CallUnboundCMethod0(&__pyx_umethod_PyList_Type_pop, L);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyDict_Values’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4532:83: error: too many arguments to function ‘(PyObject * (*)(PyObject *, PyObject * const*, Py_ssize_t))__pyx_umethod_PyDict_Type_values.func’
                   (PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x030600B1 && (cfunc)->flag == METH_FASTCALL ?  (*(__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)(cfunc)->func)(self, &PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_empty_tuple, 0), 0, NULL) :\
                                                                                      ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:235119:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_CallUnboundCMethod0’
             return __Pyx_CallUnboundCMethod0(&__pyx_umethod_PyDict_Type_values, d);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Compile failed: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInit7wtk6co2.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInit7wtk6co2.o
    /tmp/xmlXPathInit7wtk6co2.c:2:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
     main (int argc, char **argv) {
     ^~~~
    cc tmp/xmlXPathInit7wtk6co2.o -lxml2 -o a.out
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of lxml
Command "/home/test7/myweb/env/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-o_pr8d68/lxml/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-fdtp18kj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/test7/myweb/env/include/site/python3.7/lxml" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-o_pr8d68/lxml/
```

python 3.7 should only go with lxml > 4.0. I already tried of desperation lxml < 4.0 with expected no success.
It does not matter which version of 4.0 < lxml < 4.4.1

Any help appreciated how to get sofort lib into my virtualenv.

best regards

Answer (score 6):

[`sofort` declares dependency](https://github.com/spreecode/python-sofort/blob/0d467e8fd56462b2d8a0ba65085ffd9a5a4d1add/setup.py#L94) `lxml >= 3.5, < 4.0` so `pip` uses the latest suitable version lxml 3.8. The version is rather old and doesn't provide wheels for Python 3.7, [only for 2.6-3.6](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/3.8.0/#files). Perhaps the version is not compatible with Python 3.7 and cannot be compiled from sources.

Downgrade to Python 3.6. And ping `sofort` authors to upgrade. Or better send them a pull request.